# Last Record in Column, SQLALCHEMY

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I tried to get last record in my column using this

```
 ObjectRes.query.order_by('-id').first()
```

But the result is : None

I tried using all other queries, The only thing that works is

```
obj = ObjectRes.query.all()
return str(obj[-1].id)
```

The query is too heavy, Need lighter queries that work with this on Pythonanywhere. Thanks

Comment: First of all, what does "last record in column" mean to you? `'-id'` is a Djangoism. Use `order_by(ObjectRes.id.desc())` or such, but getting None as a result from your first query is weird to say the least and you should provide a [mcve] with example data. That "only working thing" is giving you indeterminate results, because without an explicit ordering the results of an SQL query have unspecified order.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Columns in SQLAlchemy models have methods attached to produce this behaviour. To order by ID descending, do this:

```
descending = Object.query.order_by(Object.id.desc())
last_item = descending.first()
```

Specifying `Object.field` is the clearest syntax for choosing a field to order by, and all columns / model attributes should support `.desc()` or `.asc()`

You can of course do this in a one liner as well:

```
last_item = Object.query.order_by(Object.id.desc()).first()
```

Answer (score -2):

I'd comment, but I need 50 rep, so, sorry deveruinseverything, im going to ruin your answer and say it's incomplete (joke).  Although, it could be Sqlalchemy has changed in the last 4 years, and not your fault at all.

You need to add `(Object)` between `.query` and `.order_by`

two line answer should look like:

> descending = Object.query(Object).order_by(Object.id.desc())
> last_item = descending.first()

One line answer should look like:

> last_item = Object.query(Object).order_by(Object.id.desc()).first()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is incorrect - you only need to pass the model in the query if you are querying like this: `session.query(Object)`.

Comment: The OP (and the other existing answer are using Flask-SQLAlchemy style syntax, which enables `Model.query.filter(..)` style queries. Legacy vanilla SQLAlchemy used `session.query(Model).filter(...)`.  This answer seems to be a mish-mash of both.